# ogr2ogr Warning 1: layer names ignored in combination with -sql

Tags: openstreetmap, ogr, ogr2ogr

When I run ogr2ogr command to export some  specific polygons from .osm.pbf file, downloaded from OSM, I get an error `Warning 1: layer names ignored in combination with -sql`.
I use `-sql` tag to get get all polygons with defined amenity,  leisure, bulding, ect...
I also define costum `osmconf.ini` file for OSM driver to read some field I want to use. This step is configured usin `-oo` command

This is full command.

```
ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" osm_bldgs_exp4.gpkg us-latest.osm.pbf multipolygons -sql "select * from multipolygons where amenity is not null or leisure is not null or shop is not null or tourism is not null or historic is not null or building not in ('yes', null)" -overwrite -progress -oo CONFIG_FILE="C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\share\gdal\osmconf.ini"
```

Process continues to go on, but I am not sure what to expect in a final result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the basic ogr2ogr command the data source and layer are given as

```
ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" osm_bldgs_exp4.gpkg us-latest.osm.pbf multipolygons
```

That would convert everything from the layer "multipolygons".

When the command includes `-sql` the layer is defined in the SQL statement:

`select * from multipolygons where ...`

That overrides the layer name in the basic command. If the command is

`ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" osm_bldgs_exp4.gpkg us-latest.osm.pbf multipolygons -sql "select * from points ...`

you can safely expect that you will get whatever is selected by the SQL and data comes from the table "points". Remove the layer name from the basic command when you use `-sql` option and the warning will go away.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Would ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" osm_bldgs_exp_test.gpkg us-latest.osm.pbf multipolygons -where "amenity is not null" -overwrite -progress also do the job?

Comment: Yes, that would do the same. Even `-where "amenity is not null OR leisure is not null"` should work. Parameter -sql is definitely needed if you want to use SQL functions in the selection.